# Adding rows to a column

Tags: average, rows, extend

Can anybody help me in the following:
I want to increase a column length by adding a an average value after each five rows. (i.e, if I have 10 rows, the output should be 12 rows, the 6th one will be the average of the first 5 rows, and the 12th one will be the average of the second 5 rows.)

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: use appropriate tags so that people find your question easily.

Comment: python? excel? google sheets? java?...

Answer (score 0):

Let's Try this One

```
import statistics
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
final_list=[]
j=0
for i in range(0,len(x),5):
    mean=statistics.mean(x[i:i+5])
    final_list=final_list+x[i:i+5]
    final_list.insert(j+i+5,mean)
    j=j+1
print(final_list)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Jia. but what if I have 2 columnns?

Comment: if your list size is not multiple of 5 then it give mean of  remain element at last

Comment: for two element [1,2] it gives [1,2,1.5] , if you do not want this answer you can add one extra condition of if/else